# Where is the user manual for the Novel class?

Tags: documentation

I'm interested in the recent `novel` class. I tried `texdoc novel` to get the documentation but all it gave was an interesting puff for the class and saying that the user manual was in HTML format. I went to my

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel
```

directory where the class and other files were but no HTML file. I tried backing up in the directory structure but didn't find any user manual for `novel.cls`.

Can anyone suggest where it might be?

PS. I think that the author might be more generous in what you get via `texdoc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `texdoc -l novel` to get a complete list of all documentation. Simply pick the one you want to see.

Comment: I didn't know about the `-l` option for `texdoc`.

Comment: @PeterWilson Note that if you use `texdoc` you get only the documentation as of your TeX distribution, not the latest documentation that is on CTAN. (This may make sense as in some sense you get the documentation for the version of the package that you have installed, but you miss on improvements in documentation that still apply to the version you have.)

Answer (score 7):

I am the author of the document class, so I know!

There is no PDF documentation. It is in HTML format. When you install the package (or download the TDS from CTAN) the HTML documentation comes with it.

This is a LuaLaTeX-only package, so its TeX files are installed in (texroot)/tex/lualatex/novel, and its docs are in (texroot)/doc/lualatex/novel.

As was noted, last week I uploaded a version that has the HTML in a single file, so it can be read directly from CTAN. Click "HTML Documentation" link there.

The document class has actually been used for a novel (with cover artwork) submitted as PDF/X-1a:2001 and accepted on first attempt by a major American P.O.D. service.

Currently, I am revising the documentation again, and working out a few minor bugs that hardly any users will encounter. But don't let that stop you. By the time you understand the current usage, the newer version will be up.

You can find a complete (public domain) novel, with cover, created using this package. Find it in the "other" folder at the GitHub project page:

https://github.com/RobtAll/novel

If you wonder why this document class doesn't create its own PDF documentation, the reason is simple: The class is tailored solely for print to paper (via PDF), therefore internal hyperlinks and bookmarks are prohibited. Besides, HTML looks better.

Comment: The answer deserves +1 (so: +1). But 'HTML looks better'? Better than using the novel class to typeset the documentation? Why not simply use a more suitable class? I wouldn't expect the user guide for `beamer` to use the `beamer` class....

Comment: @jon PDF has page breaks. HTML does not. Case closed!

Comment: @RobtAll You have done a lot of work (but I'm not fond of HTML although everyone has their own preferences). For me the easiest was Herb Schulz's `texdoc -l novel`.

Comment: @PeterWilson I look at it this way: The documentation for my Adobe programs is all in HTML. Doesn't even come with the program; you have to find it online. What does Adobe, inventor of PDF, know that the rest of us don't know? Also, I can't remember the last time I saw a user manual in printed form. Anyway: I know HTML well, and am currently revising the file so that it is well-scripted (and printable). Stay tuned.

Answer (score 6):

The package documentation has been recently (Version: 1.40 is from 2017/09/14, 10 days ago) rewritten and updated at CTAN. It used to be a bunch of separate HTML files and now it is a single one. If you go to https://ctan.org/pkg/novel and click on the [Pack­age doc­u­men­ta­tion (HTML)](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/luatex/latex/novel/doc/novel-documentation.html) link, you can see the single-file HTML documentation now.

Answer (score 3):

In `/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/novel/` there is an HTML file called `noveldocs-01-overview.html` which seems to be the (start page of the)  docs. Hence,

```
texdoc noveldocs-01-overview.html
```

will open it. There are more parts, but these are linked in the menu on the right hand side.

(Or `texdoc -l novel` in which case it's the second entry.)

Alternatively, you can find it on CTAN:

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/novel?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

In MiKTeX you can find the documentation at

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\novel.pdf
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\extras\novel-example.pdf
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\extras\novel-Gallery-ChapterStart.pdf
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\extras\NovelDeco-glyphs.pdf
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-01-overview.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-02-class-options.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-03-metadata-pdfx.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-04-layout.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-05-fonts.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-06-header-footer.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-07-text-size-style.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-08-images.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-09-chapters-displays.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-10-cover-art.html
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\lualatex\novel\noveldocs-11-debugging.html
```

Does your directory `novel` have the files `noveldocs...`?